How to increase page title font size in twenty seventeen wordpress theme for static home page and single column option
I am using twenty seventeen word press theme. The home page is set to static page and page layout is set to one column. I want to increase the font size of the page title for static front page(or home page) but not able to do so.  I changed the code as below which changes the title for all other menus items and I want the same font size for the front page also.
body.page:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page) .entry-title  {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 0.14em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

I checked the css and other files but not able to find where exactly to change. Will be very helpful if someone can point out where to change.
Thanks,

The :not(.twentyseventeen-front-page) in the existing rule you have means don't apply this CSS rule to the front page. So if you do want to apply the CSS rule to the front page, remove the :not() so that the CSS rule looks like:
body.page .entry-title {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0.14em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


Hi, Thanks for responding. I tried that earlier as per your suggestion in which case it does not work.  By having this line ":not(.twentyseventeen-front-page)" it does the trick but then its only for all the pages except frontpage.  The front page or home page title is getting over written in some program which I am not able to identify.
